How to save multiple versions of the same plot with different data series as a pdf using a macro?
I would like to save multiple versions of the same plot with different data sets as a single pdf.  Right now my code saves each plot individually to a separate folder (Charts in this case) based on the user inputting a "y" for a particular data set. The user may want to plot 100+ charts so I don't want to copy and make a new sheet with a plot for each one.
I can also utilize the Bluebeam plugin if there is a solution going that route, but I am very unfamiliar with that plugin.
Sub NewChartDataRewrite()
Dim LastFigRow As Long
Dim FigRangeName As String
 FigRangeName = ("I3:I")
 LastFigRow = FindLastRow()

Dim FigYes As Range
Set FigYes = Worksheets("Bulk Calc").Range(FigRangeName & LastFigRow)

    For Each cell In FigYes

        If UCase(cell.Value) = "Y" Then

'Saves charts as indiviual PDFs
            Dim NewPath As String
            Dim NewFolder As String
            Dim ActivePath As String
        
            ActivePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
            NewPath = ActivePath & "\Charts\"
            NewFolder = Dir(NewPath, vbDirectory)
            
            If NewFolder = "" Then
            MkDir NewPath
            End If
            
            Dim SaveNameString As String
            SaveNameString = Sheets("Bulk Calc").Range("'Bulk Calc'!$L$" & cell.Row).Value
  
            Sheets("Chart (0)").Select
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
            
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewPath & SaveNameString _
            , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
            :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next
End Sub



Function FindLastRow() As Long
 
    Sheets("Bulk NIC").Select
    Cells(2, 1).Select
 

    FindLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
                    

End Function

As stated, I am able to save the plot with different data individually but would like to build a pdf of each new plot to have a single pdf with 100+ pages rather than 100+ individual pdf's with a single page.

What is the specific challenge you're having with getting started on this?

This may be of use

@TimWilliams My challenge is to either save each chart as a separate page in one large pdf or to combine the multiple single paged pdf's into one.  I saw your comment on the post cybernetic.nomad linked stating "There's no built-in mechanism for doing this in Excel VBA: pretty sure you will need a 3rd party tool/library." The linked post is similar to what I would like to do; do you know if there is a way to do it using the bluebeam plugin?

Sorry I don't know anything about Bluebeam.  One alternative might be to copy each chart as an image, paste them all to the same worksheet, then export that worksheet to PDF.

@TimWilliams no worries. I thought about your solution of copying each chart and pasting into a single worksheet, but I'm trying to avoid creating multiple charts at the same time because there may be 100+ and I'm concerned about VBA processing so many charts.

You can use a single chart and just copy it as a picture inside a loop - no need for 100+ separate charts...   I've done this in the past and it works pretty well.

Here's a simple example using a single chart and a loop with copy-as-picture to compile all charts onto a single worksheet:
Sub ChartLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As Chart, rw As Range, posTop As Long
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsOut = wb.Worksheets("Charts")
    
    'reference an existing chart to be adjusted in the loop below
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart 
    
    posTop = 5
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A2:E15").Rows    'loop over source Y values
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rw   'adjust chart data
        '...set title, etc
        cht.CopyPicture                       'copy...
        wsOut.Paste
        With wsOut.Shapes(wsOut.Shapes.Count) 'adjust the pasted chart image
            .Left = 5
            .Top = posTop
            posTop = posTop + .Height + 5     'next top position
            'optionally (eg) add a page break
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub

